# Which .jar file in JDK be loaded when one project configure with JDK?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-8

In my IntelliJ IDEA when configure the JDK and choose JDK home for one project then below classpath/jar file will be loaded.

But as I know there be some jar file in JDK home path not be loaded,

for example this file below the same path not be loaded yet
:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security/policy/limited/US_export_policy.jar.

How this take effect? Can I choose special design JDK and load some jar in other place? where can I change the load rule, in IDEA or in JDK source code?

```
jar:///Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/charsets.jar!/
jar:///Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/deploy.jar!/
jar:///Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar!/
jar:///Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar!/
jar:///Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar!/
jar:///Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar!/
jar:///Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar!/
jar:///Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar!/
jar:///Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar!/
jar:///Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar!/
jar:///Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar!/
jar:///Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar!/
jar:///Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/javaws.jar!/
jar:///Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jce.jar!/
jar:///Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfr.jar!/
jar:///Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfxswt.jar!/
jar:///Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jsse.jar!/
jar:///Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/management-agent.jar!/
jar:///Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/plugin.jar!/
jar:///Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/resources.jar!/
jar:///Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar!/
jar:///Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/ant-javafx.jar!/
jar:///Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/dt.jar!/
jar:///Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/javafx-mx.jar!/
jar:///Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/jconsole.jar!/
jar:///Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/packager.jar!/
jar:///Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/sa-jdi.jar!/
jar:///Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar!/
```

Comment: I think all these jars are required, because, Intelij read these jars from lib folder automatically. What exactly the problem you are facing :)

Comment: I just want know why these .jar files mentioned be  loaded? Intellij set the rule according to  special classpaths?  In eclipse the loaded .jar files from JDK are different. where can I change the classpaths and include another classpath?

Comment: You are not supposed to mess around with these jars. Java 9 already got rid of them. Don’t waste further effort on them.

Answer (score 0):

You could configure classpath in "Project Structure | SDKs - Classpath"

Comment: Yes this could be configure the parent classpath，but why some .jar file in the parent classpath be loaded, but others not. There should be another rule.

Comment: What JARs aren't loaded?

Comment: Why some JARs be loaded in /jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/ , but others not ? Who made the ruler? Where can I found?

Comment: Only JARS under "security" folder aren't loaded. Do you face any issue with it?

Comment: That's true!But where the rule defined and can I change according my willing?Because this not transparence for me and let me feel not well. :)